If $\{f_n\}$ converges almost everywhere to $f$, and there exists $M>0$ such that $|f_n(x)|\leq M$ a.e., then $|f(x)|\leq M$ a.e.

Prove that if $\{f_n\}$ converges almost everywhere to $f$, and there exists $M>0$ such that $|f_n(x)|\leq M$ almost everywhere, then $|f(x)|\leq M$ almost everywhere.

How do I prove this? What kind of theorem should I use? Thanks.

You should add possible strategies, your attempts, where you got stuck etc.

actually, the orginal problem is: "Suppose that the sequence ${f_{n}}$ converges to $f$ and the sequence ${g_{n}}$ converges to $g$ in measure on a measurable set $E$. It is known that $|f_{n}(x)| \leq M$ and $|g_{n}(x)| \leq M$ almost everywhere on $E$ for all $n$. Prove that:
$$
|f(x)| \leq M \quad \text{and} \quad |g(x)| \leq M \quad \text{almost everywhere on } E.
$$
"

@Tina So, if i can prove the above problem, I can prove the original problem

To prove that if $\{f_n\}$ converges almost everywhere to $f$, and there exists a constant $M > 0$ such that $|f_n(x)| \leq M$ almost everywhere, then $|f(x)| \leq M$ almost everywhere, we can follow these steps:
Definitions and Assumptions

$\{f_n\}$ converges almost everywhere to $f$, meaning there exists a set $E$ with measure zero such that for $x \notin E$, $\lim_{n \to \infty} f_n(x) = f(x)$.
There exists $M > 0$ such that $|f_n(x)| \leq M$ almost everywhere, i.e., there exists a set $F$ of measure zero where this inequality might fail, but for all $x \notin F$, $|f_n(x)| \leq M$.
Define the set $Z = E \cup F$, which has measure zero. Outside $Z$, both the convergence and the boundedness hold.

Working on the Set Where Both Conditions Hold
For $x \notin Z$, we know two things:

$\lim_{n \to \infty} f_n(x) = f(x)$,
$|f_n(x)| \leq M$ for all $n$.

Now, take the limit as $n \to \infty$ on both sides of the inequality $|f_n(x)| \leq M$:
$\lim_{n \to \infty} |f_n(x)| \leq M$.
Since $\lim_{n \to \infty} f_n(x) = f(x)$, we have:
$\lim_{n \to \infty} |f_n(x)| = |f(x)|$.
Thus, we conclude that:
$|f(x)| \leq M \quad \text{for all } x \notin Z$.
Conclusion
Since the set $Z = E \cup F$ has measure zero, the inequality $|f(x)| \leq M$ holds almost everywhere. Therefore, $|f(x)| \leq M$ almost everywhere as required.
This completes the proof.

I think this is essentially correct. It may be worth noting why $F$ has measure zero. I'm not sure it's clear from the wording, but I believe the assumption is "for each $n$, $|f_n(x)| \leq M$ almost everywhere", in which case you'd need to take a countable union of null sets. But either way the argument would be almost the same.
